# How to report a user

Tags: support, chat, users

Every once in a while we get a question about how to report a bad user to the administrators. Sometimes it's a spammer, sometimes it's a troll, and sometimes it's just someone who had a momentary blip in the "socially acceptable" filter.

But my question is how to report one user. He is always performing to ask the question, he is going to the chat room, he gives all the code and plead to solve his problem. I warned many times, but he is always doing that with other developers.

You can ask me why you are going to report him. Because he didn't work for his project; he always get work from the SO members.

Note: I think he is a junior developer...

Comment: Find one of his posts, probably best to find one that’s the most symptomatic of the issues, and raise a custom flag on it for the mods, describing the pattern of behavior of the *user* (ie make it clear you’re not taking about just this one post).

Comment: Asking for help is NOT spam, in any way.

Comment: No i'm not talking his one Post I think these past one week i saw minimum 5 posts like that after he got an answer he delete the chat room comment

Comment: @ShadowWizard I accept that. But check this link you can find the problem https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166880/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-cemal

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've already warned them and they didn't stop (that should be the first step). If that didn't work, you can ask one of the room owners to give him a final warning. Room owners have the ability to 'kick' users out of the room for a short period of time. Chances are this will improve their behaviour; if not, you can resort to a custom moderator flag on one of their messages. But ♦ moderators usually have less context to work with than room owners, so it's harder for them to take the right decision.

Comment: I think OP is concerned with the user’s Q&A activity, in addition to their use of chat.